# In MySQL will UNIQUE index act as fast lookup for varchar column?

Tags: mysql

If I have a column `short_title` in MySQL table and it is defined as UNIQUE, do I also have to add FULLTEXT for it to be searchable really fast? Or does UNIQUE already guarantee it will be searchable quickly (without full table scan)?

Thanks, Boda Cydo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNIQUE` will locate the verbatim `short_title` using the underlying index.

If you need a word match (as opposed to verbatim match), use `FULLTEXT` index.

Also note that by default the `B-Tree` indexes in `MyISAM` against the `VARCHAR` columns are subject to key compression. This can slow down the searches for the titles closer to the end of the alphabet:

- [**Index search time depends on the value being searched**](http://explainextended.com/2010/02/04/index-search-time-depends-on-the-value-being-searched/)

Finally, the `VARCHAR` keys tend to be large in size.

For the fastest verbatim searches, you should store a `MD5` hash of the title in a `BINARY(16)` column, create a `UNIQUE` index over it (disabling the key compression) and search for the hash.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer. But does it mean then that I have to have both UNIQUE and FULLTEXT indexes on short_title column for it to be UNIQUE and quickly searchable at the same time?

Comment: I got it. I am doing verbatim match (I think I understand it right - it's matching the whole column), so I need only UNIQUE index. :)